# select dates that are between current date and 3 month from the current date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to select all dates that are between the current date and 3 months before.
I tried using this query but it isn't working right.

```
$sql = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM date 
    WHERE d_date BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
");
```

Please if you could help me write the right syntax.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided the error message.

Comment: The syntax is right but no number can be `BETWEEN 7 AND 4`, the `BETWEEN` operator is not working exactly as the "between" in common English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to swap your bounaries, and it will work:

```
SELECT * FROM date
WHERE d_date BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND now()
```

For example, this query returns true ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1698/25)):

```
SELECT (now() - interval 1 month)
    BETWEEN now() - interval 3 month AND now()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE anydate_col BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL +3 MONTH)
```